# Average across multiple columns with varying data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 10 decimal columns and I would like to add a computed column to my table that contains the average of these 10. A complication is that not every record has all 10 columns filled in. Some records have 4 some have 8 and some have 10.

e.g.

```
ID D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 D10
1  12 19 13 14
2  32 53 34 54 65 34 12 09
3  41 54 33 61 71 12 09 08 08 12
```

How can I get the average of these where ID1 = 14.5, ID2 = 36.625 etc

I can't just do D1 + D2 + D3... / 10 as the 10 isn't always 10

The ideal would just be to do AVG(D1:D10) but clearly the world isn't ideal!

Comment: Columns, not fields... Don't store data like that ("horizontally"), store vertically instead and everything will become much easier.

Comment: I can't change the structure at this point

Answer (score 3):

You can't use AVG aggregate function (because it works on rows) but you can calculate an average using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    (ISNULL(D1,0) + ISNULL(D2,0) + 
    ISNULL(D3,0) + ISNULL(D4,0) + ISNULL(D5,0) + 
    ISNULL(D6,0) + ISNULL(D7,0) + ISNULL(D8,0) + 
    ISNULL(D9,0) + ISNULL(D10,0)) /
    CASE 
    WHEN 
        D1 IS NOT NULL 
        OR D2 IS NOT NULL
        OR D3 IS NOT NULL
        OR D4 IS NOT NULL
        OR D5 IS NOT NULL
        OR D6 IS NOT NULL
        OR D7 IS NOT NULL
        OR D8 IS NOT NULL
        OR D9 IS NOT NULL
        OR D10 IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        (
        CASE
            WHEN D1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE
            WHEN D2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE
            WHEN D3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE
            WHEN D4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE
            WHEN D5 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE
            WHEN D6 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE
            WHEN D7 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE
            WHEN D8 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE
            WHEN D9 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE
            WHEN D10 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END
        )
   ELSE 1
   END
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: If you use columns instead rows... the only method is that.

Comment: Yeah I was going to answer this but couldn't be bothered writing it out. The reason this is so complicated is that the data is not normalized. I would consider whether you really can't change it at this point because it's going to continue to cause problems like this.

Comment: @ChrisV: Yes, that table is not normalized. A great problem, but our friend can have inherited that structure, so he can't change it.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate the structure isn't ideal for this type of thing.

Comment: @GordonCopestake: If all values are NULL you divide by1 (so you have 0/1 = 0) else apply the formula. (show the edited answer)

Comment: Thanks Joe, thats spot on

Answer (score 1):

AVG for each id:

```
select id, avg(d) from
(
select id, id1 as d from tablename
union all
select id, id2 as d from tablename
union all
select id, id3 as d from tablename
union all
select id, id4 as d from tablename
union all
select id, id5 as d from tablename
union all
select id, id6 as d from tablename
union all
select id, id7 as d from tablename
union all
select id, id8 as d from tablename
union all
select id, id9 as d from tablename
union all
select id, id10 as d from tablename)
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Values` table valued constructor to `unpivot` the data then find `average` per `ID`. Try this

```
select id,avg(data) from Yourtable 
cross apply 
(values(D1), (D2), (D3), (D4), (D5), (D6) ,(D7), (D8), (D9) ,(D10)) cs (data)
group by id
```

Or if your want decimal values then use this.

```
select id,sum(data)/sum(case when data is not null then 1.0 else 0 end) from Yourtable 
cross apply 
(values(D1), (D2), (D3), (D4), (D5), (D6) ,(D7), (D8), (D9) ,(D10)) cs (data)
group by id
```